# How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps with AdoptOpenJDK?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, internationalization, adoptopenjdk

I have a webapp where I'm using Java/JSP pages and a Tomcat 9 Server.

When I'm using the Tomcat Server with a Oracle Java version (1.8.0_211), I don't not have any encodung errors.

Now, I've added a new Tomcat 9 Server but with the AdoptOpen JDK 11.0.4+11 version and started my application and here my application shows some encoding problems.
Instead of an 'ä' I'll get an �.
This problem occures when I load the stored strings in the properties.

The moment I switch to the version 1.8. I don't have the problem anymore.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How do you read the property file?

Comment: Thx! (<-- going to bash my head against something) I'm reading it like this 
´new String((ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages").getString(key)).getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")´ .... but thats code I've created months ago and forgot about it.....
Changeds to 'new String((ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages").getString(key)).getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")' - Problem solved